# Reuse Functions PHP to save into a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to reuse a function to save the grabbed variable of "Price" with different names. The code I'm hoping to reuse by throwing a string to change the value of $nameP

```
Function GrabPrice(&$nameP){
    $sql = "select Price from sub product where name='".$nameP."'";
    $resultTest = mysql_query($sql);
    $TempPrice = mysql_fetch_array($resultTest);
    return $tempPrice[0];
}

$part1 = GrabPrice("part number");
$part2 = GrabPrice("another part number");
```

The command does save the price in the array [0] but it has trouble storing the data when I  have it as a reusable function.  I just don't want to write the function for individual part numbers.

EDIT: I'm trying to save the variable return from GrabPrice() into the $part1...$part2 by passing a string to replace the $nameP.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Why a you declaring `$nameP` as a reference parameter, then passing string literals to it? Doesn't that give an error?

Comment: @BobbyJack Yes: `PHP Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "reusable function". What kind of function isn't? remove the `&` so that you're not passing by reference and it will be ok. Though you may get undefinded index warning if the sql result set is empty

Comment: I'm also not sure you're including verbatim code - does your database table really include a space in the name and, if so, shouldn't you be quoting it? (unless that's actually just a redundant alias)

Comment: @BobbyJack no sorry its whole part numbers. i was just using that as an example. sorry if i didn't clarify i was trying to pass the string into the function. and use the string i pass as the $nameP variable, if that makes sense. save the price from the database of that part number. into the variable $part1...$part2

Comment: What's the problem? Are you seeing an error? What values are you seeing for `$part1` and `$part2`?

Comment: All of the mysql_* functions have been deprecated...now is the time to move to mysqli_*. http://php.net/mysql_query

Comment: I'm not getting any values for part 1 and/or part 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function GrabPrice($nameP){
    $sql = "select Price from sub product where name='".$nameP."'";
    $resultTest = mysql_query($sql);
    $TempPrice = mysql_fetch_array($resultTest);
    return $tempPrice[0];
}

$part1 = GrabPrice("part number");
$part2 = GrabPrice("another part number");
```

Passing by reference in the case of your function is entirely useless since the strings being passed aren't assigned to a variable, and do not need to have their alterations stored. Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will no longer be available. Use either MySQLi or PDO for your MySQL needs.

Also how you use `mysql_query` is dangerous and more than likely will not work when you transition from mysql to mysqli. However, on the assumption that you continue to use `mysql_`functions, you should alter your function as such

```
Function GrabPrice($nameP){
    global $conn //Assuming your mysql_connect is stored in this variable.
    $sql = "select Price from sub product where name='".mysql_real_escape_string($nameP)."'"; 
    //Protects against SQL Injection, which you should google.
    $resultTest = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
    $TempPrice = mysql_fetch_array($resultTest,$conn);
    mysql_free_result($resultTest);
    return $tempPrice[0];
}

$part1 = GrabPrice("part number");
$part2 = GrabPrice("another part number");
```

I really do recommend looking up some tutorials for either MySQLi or PDO. I personally prefer MySQLi, but truth be told both have their strong points and both have their weak points.

Comment: Thank you for that. I didn't add any security to it yet, but i was just testing to before i started making it more secure. and Mysqli i will be working on soon. but thank you for the advice

Comment: Security should be a concern from the moment you begin your application. I speak on that accord from experience. In larger projects you may *mean* to go back and change some SQL/PHP syntax to be more secure, but after 300 files and probably a million (only a mild use of hyperbole) lines of code later, it's hard to remember which ones you wanted to tweak.

Comment: @Jhecht Unrelated but I usually add a `//TODO:Check whatever` as a comment. Most IDEs I use detect this (eclipse for example) and adds it in a todo list window

Comment: Everybody's got their own system I suppose. I know I get too wrapped up in other portions that I end up forgetting and unless I leave myself a very explicit (i.e., whole lot of curse words) note somewhere in the code that immediately catches my attention or causes me problems, I'll forget.